# TexMaker stopped compiling but doesn't show errors or new version of pdf

Tags: texmaker

I am using TexMaker to write my master thesis, already since almost six months. All of the sudden, the compiling stopped working. I press compile, everything seems as if it is compiling, but then once I click on view pdf none of my changes show up. I also doenst give me any error. And if I purposly include an error on the code, it doesnt show when I compile. I tried an old version that I was sure was working, and the same happens so I think the problem isn't in the code, but in the software. Any ideas?

When I run Path in my cmd window, this is what I get:

> PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows
>   Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine
>   Components\DAL;C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
>   2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;

Comment: Did you try compiling document _not_ via TeXmaker but using e.g. the command line?

Comment: (If you are not using Windows, please ignore my comment(s)). Go to command line and type `pdflatex`, for example. If you get `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141...`, then it's ok, otherwise your TeX distribution is installed not correctly or is having some bugs...

Comment: In the windows explorer go to the folder of your document. Then type in the address line `cmd` and hit enter. This will open a command line window. There you can type `pdflatex name-of-your-tex-file`

Comment: thank you @JouleV. When I run it it says - 'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I tried running it on overleaf and it works, but I would really prefer to work in texmaker. Ive already unistalled and reinstalled a new version. Do you know how else I could find the bug?

Comment: @Maria You don't have a TeX distribution installed, so `pdflatex` is not recognized. Have you installed MiKTeX or TeX Live _before_ Texmaker?

Comment: If you can not run> pdflatex from the cmd window then you could try run> **WHERE /r \ pdfLaTeX** that should report a folder name if its installed which needs to be added to the path

Comment: @JouleV no, I had my template from my uni so I basically just installed Texmaker and it's been working fine for the past four months. Why would it only now need me to install something extra?

Comment: If you can't run `pdflatex` at the moment, but you can compile the document last month, it is very strange, and I don't understand what's going on. I think you were compiling the document with Overleaf, right? Anyway, now you need to uninstall Texmaker, then install TeX Live or MiKTeX, then install Texmaker again.

Comment: @KJO I got "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" back. How do I add it now to the path?

Comment: @JouleV I was using texmaker always, I only tested it today for the first time on overleaf to see if it was a problem with the code or with if it was a problem from texmaker. Since it worked there, I guess it's in texmaker. If you see what I wrote to KJO, I think it means that I do have miktex installed, no?

Comment: at cmd see what path is run > PATH that should give you a long list but you would need to post that in question for us to guess why its not working

Comment: @KJO, I edited the question here on top with the list. Is that what you meant? I recently installed git and tortoise git, thats the only new thing that changed since the last time I've used texmaker. Could that have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: OK looks like something has mixed it up a bit so need to correct the ending should not have a \ or not " and not very last entry ; need to go to environment settings and clean it up its the line for git starting with " that started the problem

Comment: @KJO windows 10! Ok, so I should edit the environment variables and delete the line for git? I don't really know how I can "clean it up"...

Comment: @KJO I deleted everything that I had recently added and it doesn't show up in the path anymore. It's still not working though :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this issue is resolved as this comment indicates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481495/texmaker-stopped-compiling-but-doesnt-show-errors-or-new-version-of-pdf#comment1217203_481540

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems with a previously working system because something upset the Path variables then you need to work through the following steps First check we have a pathing issue

[image]

**This folder is the one that needs to be in the system path so we need to add or correct any corrupted existing entry.**

There are two path settings in windows and when they are combined one can impact the other for the MiKTeX entry there should be NOTHING after the folder \bin (for32bit users) OR \bin\x64 (for 64bit users) so in this 64bit case we remove any thing after the 4

MiKTeX may not be the only wrong entry and will not work if it is lower than a bad entry so look at the adjoining ones in case they were corrupted or entered incorrectly

**If MiKTeX is the last entry consider promoting it by using the "Move Up" button on the right**

[image]

In windows 10 the easiest way to get access is via Cortana search
[image]

**Once you have updated the paths to a suitable clean state it is important to reboot first so you check they will stick on next start-up but more importantly so all affected applications see the settings anew.**

MiKTeX will most likely have been impacted by the path changes so it is best to fire up MiKTeX-console (as single user and if in dual setting also as admin).
**From the TASKS pulldown run `Refresh filename database` and `Refresh font map files`.**

Whilst in MiKTeX-console you can check that settings directories looks reasonable especially the lack of an error for link target directory

To retest all is good with paths use explore to browse to your directory that has a tex file and in the top address bar overwrite the entry with cmd then hit the enter key and you will be in a terminal console window for that directory > `pdfLaTeX -version` should respond with a version message and `pdfLaTeX YourTeXfileName` should stream a lot of compilation messages and eventually produce at the end of a good run a YourTeXfileName.pdf

[image]

If there were problems then the YourTeXfileName.log can help determine why so would be needed. At this stage the TeX engine is producing a PDF so should be working. Now attention can shift to the editor.

**If TeX applications are confused by the changed system settings they may need to be reset so they can reconfigure.**

[image]

Comment: thanks. I now have the path that I've updated in the question on top, already cleaned up. When I type pdflatex in cmd I already get "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)" . The latex compilling however still doesn't work. Was there something else I should've done?

Comment: If you get a reply from pdfLaTeX at prompt (it shows its version) then you can in the way Ulrike mentioned go to the folder and as she suggests pdfLaTeX myfile which should compile a PDF IF Texmaker cannot do it for you then the chances are it may need to be significantly reset or re-installed since it seems to have lost the plot (i.e. wrong paths confused it)

Comment: IT IS possible that MiKTeX got disturbed so need to run> MiKTeX-console TASKS Update filename database & fonts

Comment: I see in your edit you seem to have the MiKTeX  folder twice and the second one has a; after the 4 thus its best to delete that 2nd entry

Comment: I have updated the path again, and edited on top. Now only time shows up. Still doesnt work. I also did what you said and ran Miktex-console tasks on cmd, I checked for updated and updated everything there was. Don't know exactly if thats what you meants with update filename database and fonts. How exactly would I do that if not?

Comment: You ran tex files before so have some that you know are good to rerun manually or can test using the TeXworks editor that should be available from left side of MiKTeX-console you can file open a copy of one of them. we need to check if it is the MiKTeX system instability that's causing problems rather than your Texmaker

Comment: Its working already, I did a reset of the settings by recommendation of latex staff and it worked!

Comment: Glad its sorted you may note the reset of settings was at the end of my answer once the path was sorted. I will add one more image to the answer in case others have a similar problem